# How to send HTML content in message body using contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

[image: I want to send HTML content using contact form 7, but HTML code is not work direct send HTML tag in email. so how can I send this type of message using the hook or any way ?]

I want to send HTML content using contact form 7, but HTML code is not working direct send HTML tag in email. so how can I send this type of message using the hook or any way?

I am using hook "wpcf7_posted_data" to append my extra HTML tag in body text.
I want to send extra HTML format data before send an email.

```
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) {
    $html .= '<table>';
    $html .='<tr><td>'.$product->get_Name().'</td></tr>';
    $html .='<tr><td>'.$display.'</td></tr>';
    $html .='<tr><td>Qty : '.$ProductQty.'</td></tr>';
    $html .= '</table>';
    $value = $array['message'];
    if( !empty( $value ) ){       
        $array['message'] = $value."<br><br>".$html;
    }
    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: <table><tr><td>Testing</td></tr></table> this data send in email as HTML format not in HTML tag.

Comment: Means you want to send HTML in the mail after form submission?

Comment: yes, I want like this.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but not like this. I want from the front side. The user will fillup the form with an HTML tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211211/discussion-between-krupal-panchal-and-dhirendrasinh-drc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to append data to the Contact Form 7 email HTML.  The below code will do that. However, it appears that you're using some other variables that I wasn't sure where you were getting them from.  All of the submitted form fields will be in `$posted_data` in my function below.  You can trigger the process on the existence of a field, or just run it every time.  You can also use `global $product` and get variables to complete your table.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'he_append_to_email_body' );
function he_append_to_email_body( $contact_form ) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();    
    }

    if (isset($posted_data['the_field_you_want_to_trigger_this'])) { // Check that your field is present in your form.
        /**
         * ToDo:
         * Get your product and display and other variables here to put into the table.
         */
        $html = '<table>';
        $html .='<tr><td>'.$product->get_Name().'</td></tr>';
        $html .='<tr><td>'.$display.'</td></tr>';
        $html .='<tr><td>Qty : '.$ProductQty.'</td></tr>';
        $html .= '</table>';
        // Get the existing output from the CF7 email
        $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' );
        // Append your data after the existing
        $mail['body'] .= $html;
        // Update the mail 
        $contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your user to insert HTML in the form by himself. So you need to set layout for the sent message in the form MAIL TAB itself, and check the "Use HTML content type" bellow the Message body field.

You are allowed to compose your HTML, but beware that Mail protocols and clients doesn't read all HTML tags or even all CSS.
Check this link for how to create a HTML E-mail body message: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding-html-emails/
And this for allowed CSS: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

You may also send the form to another e-mail address, check the Use Mail (2)
"is an additional mail template often used as an autoresponder".

Check Contact Form 7 Documentation: https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/

Regards.
H

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but actually I am using hook "wpcf7_posted_data" for append my extra HTML tag in body text.

Comment: I feel like you're changing your question each time I get in this post!

Comment: Maybe you should do a better research using google. You may use Hidden Fields Plugin.